# Can emacs on Mac using native window system connect to an emacs server on a Linux system

Tags: osx, linux, server

At this point I believe I am using the emacs version on my Mac that is built by Homebrew and the "stock" emacs on Ubuntu 18.04.

I set up emacs server on the Ubuntu host as it is described in [Starting Emacs Daemon with systemd](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon#toc2) and connect to it using emacsclient as described.  This all works fine.

I also use emacs on my Mac with tramp to access the file systems on the Ubuntu host.  And this works fine too.  Even `magit` works which is rather spectacular.

The main reason for the emacs in daemon mode on the Ubuntu host is to replace `tmux` so if the connection drops, the shell process continues and I can later view the `*shell*` buffer.

Is there a way for me to view and interact with the `*shell*` buffer from the emacs on my Mac?

The ultimate goal here is to have just one emacs on my Mac and the ability to start and run commands on the remote Ubuntu system in such a way that if the connection drops, the remote commands continue to run and I can later connect and view the output like `tmux`, `screen`, or emacs in daemon mode can do.

Comment: So you're *not* trying to run `emacsclient` on the OSX machine and connect it to the server on the remote host; but rather you're trying to have a separate instance of Emacs interacting with a remote emacs server (but also doing its own things locally on OSX), correct?  To my knowledge you can't do that (other than by using a `term` buffer to run `emacsclient` on the remote host via ssh, which would be a bit awkward).

Comment: @phils I believe you have the question properly interpreted.  But, you gave me an idea that I will toy with... Perhaps having a local `emacsclient` connected to the Ubuntu `emacs-server` may be at least slightly better than running the `emacsclient` on the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: I hope you get that to work. emacsclient over tcp between macOS and Ubuntu is not something I've managed to get working

Comment: FYI: The closest I've come is `ssh $1 "emacsclient -n -c -e nil -u" < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1` where `$1` is the host.  When the remote host is rebooted, I ssh to the remote host and start emacs via `emacs --daemon`.  This isn't / wasn't my initial goal but it isn't too bad.